# Strange data corruption on HDD after switching from Windows to Linux

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, lvm, smart, bad-blocks

After I have replaced Windows 10 (the laptop has been in use for some time witout any issues) with Kubuntu Cosmic (ext4 over lvm, kernel 4.18.0-16-generic) on a laptop, I have started experiencing a very strange behavior.

1. Toshiba MQ01ABD100 (the hdd was bundled with laptop), heads parking is disabled (`hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda` on every boot and resume), though I still hear it on idle.
2. Filesystem is reguraliry corrupted.
3. Files, including system ones, are regularily corrupted, rigt in process of execution, resulting in software crashes.
4. S.M.A.R.T. is OK
5. long test is OK.
6. `badblocks` (nondestructive) found nothing.

Googling about firmware errors for that drive resulted in nothing.

What can it be, how to fix that and why there were no issues on Windows?